# html/css server status checker?

Tags: html, css

The idea is that i would like to be able to write it in html or css to ping an address or IP every 10 minutes to check if it bounces back a signal, and if yes, then the status on my website says its 'online', or if it doesn't receive a signal, then it changes the text on my webpage to say 'offline'. I would have no idea how to make it Interchangeable to work with several servers, so far i have only found a way to do it with cron jobs, but i'm running windows 7 and have no idea how to script it in the emulators i found. Also i'm fairly new to html and css or i would probably already know how to do this :/

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this with _just_ html/css.

Comment: What kind of "signal" is it sending back?  (I'm trying to devise a purely html solution...)

Comment: @JamesCurran: An image will work. So will a JS file.

Comment: @Blender : I know what WILL work. I need to know what I'm being allowed to work with...

Comment: The particular instance I refer to in the question is about pinging IP's/DNS's for game servers and internet sites. on my webpage I have the statuses of several servers, and its a pain to update their statuses manually every time one goes down temporarily or goes down specifically for maintenance.

Comment: btw to the people who downvoted, i appologize for the noobish question, as i stated elsewhere on this page, i am very new to programming, and did roughly an hour of research, and came up with shell scripts and thats in, but im running win7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you write a file on the external server?

If so, add a small stylesheet there which alters the following HTML:

```
<span class="online">Online</span>
<span class="offline">Offline</span>
```

from this CSS (on your server):

```
.online { display: none; }
.offline { display: inline; }
```

to this:

```
.online { display: inline; }
.offline { display: none; }
```

Make sure you link them so that the external server's stylesheet is listed *last* in your HTML header.

---

However, this pure-CSS method can **not** be repeated every ten minutes -- for that, you need JavaScript.

Make a [JSON-P](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) request to the external server, make the text default to "offline" in your HTML, and change it to "online" if the JSON-P request is successful. (JSON-P will never return an error.) However, this also requires that you have a page of your own making on that external server to return the JSON, even if it's empty.

If you don't have access to write to the external server, then there's probably not much you can do.

Comment: Ingenius... I was trying to think of something reading from the remote server into an IFRAME or IMG, but the CSS file seem nice...

Comment: I do have access to it, but I don't know jquerry. I'm relatively new, but learn fairly quick, with the information you gave me I should be able to figure it out. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: A simple refresh would work as well. But all cache must be disabled for that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a bit of JavaScript to your page for this.

You could perform an AJAX request to determine that the page is online - the AJAX request will return a 200 status code if it successfully loads the page. If the page is on a different domain to your test page, you would need either Cross Origin Requests enabled (CORS) or a JSONP response or use a proxy page on your server.

Of course, if it fails, it doesn't mean the website is offline - your connection may have dropped (for example).

Comment: Wouldn't an AJAX request be useless unless the page is on the same server?

Comment: I refer the honourable gentleman to my answer :)

Comment: well doesn't that get the "D'oh" award of the day! Put on your glasses Jimmmy and read!!

Answer (score 0):

Well You need a Server Base Script [PHP/ASP] and JavaScript with AJAX in Client Side.

You can use the Library for Javascript jQuery (http://jquery.com/) A Powerfull library that can make you save time.

Html would be something like that:

```
<div class='serverstatus'></div>
```

For php you have to make a small script like

```
$host = 'Your IP'; 
$port = your.port; 
//here you define the Server Info [IP/PORT]
$timeout = 1;
//You open a connection to that ip on that port and check if responding or not
$handler = fsockopen($host,$port,$errcd,$errstr,$timeout);
if($handler){   
   echo "1";
} else {
   echo "0"; 
} 
fclose($handler);
```

This was the PHP File now for JavaScript:

Ajax would be

```
        setTimeout(function() {$.ajax({
            url:'phpfile.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                if (data == "1") {
                    $(".serverstatus").html("Online");
                }
                else if (data == "0") {
                    $(".serverstatus").html("Offline");
                }
                else {
                    $(".serverstatus").html("Undefined");
                }

            }
        });},600000);
```

Requires jQuery Library.

For your knowledge CSS called Cascading Styled Sheet And it is used only for Design purposes. With CSS you can't script you can't do anything but Stylize your page.
HTML is used to create the HTML content , again its not used for that kind of stuff

for this u will need to learn PHP or ASP for the "Connection Part" between an external Source , and javascript for live update.

Comment: Thanks, i only started learning 3 days ago, but 18 hours of each day has been spent learning, so i know a bit of php, but i dont feel comfortable using it yet. thanks for the clarification on css, again, new to it, sorry ^.^